# Trouble extracting value from external function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a div component with a mutable class. I'll need to evaluate it later in the object's state as well, so I'm making it so that the div's class equals the "piece" state. To change the state, I have created a function in an external JS file that returns a random value from a given list, as such:

```
var pieceAssignment = function() {
    const pieceValues = [
        "blue-piece",
        "green-piece",
        "purple-piece",
        "red-piece"
    ];

    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var pieceClass = pieceValues[ i ];

    return pieceClass
}

exports.pieceAssignment = pieceAssignment;
```

I checked the function using a simple alert and it is working seemingly fine. However, I can't seem to assign it within the component itself.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var pieceAssignment = require('../util/PieceAssignment').pieceAssignment;

class X1Y1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.assignNewPiece = this.assignNewPiece.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            piece: null,
            type: 'regular',
            layers: 0,
            xCoordinate: 1,
            yCoordinate: 1,
        }
    }

    assignNewPiece() {
        var newPiece = new pieceAssignment();

        this.setState = {
            piece: newPiece
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.assignNewPiece();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="game-cell">
                <div className= { this.state.piece } onClick={ this.assignNewPiece }></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export {
    X1Y1
}
```

One of the strategies I used for debugging was to assign `this.state = {piece: new pieceAssignment()}`, in which case the component was rendered with class [Object object].

I have tried every solution I could find in 5 Google pages and still have not found a way to extract the value and correctly assign it to the div class.

Any tips?

Comment: Remove the `new` from `new pieceAssigment()`, and remember that `setState` is a function: `this.setState({ piece: newPiece })`.

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `new` from the `pieceAssigment()` call - since you're not using it as a class.

Also, remember that `setState` is a function:

```
assignNewPiece() {
    var newPiece = pieceAssignment();

    this.setState({
        piece: newPiece
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@cbr nailed the matter. Here's the working code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var pieceAssignment = require('../util/PieceAssignment').pieceAssignment;

class X1Y1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.assignNewPiece = this.assignNewPiece.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            piece: null,
            type: 'regular',
            layers: 0,
            xCoordinate: 1,
            yCoordinate: 1,
        }
    }

    assignNewPiece() {
        var newPiece = pieceAssignment();

        this.setState({ piece: newPiece });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.assignNewPiece();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="game-cell">
                <div className= { this.state.piece } onClick={ this.assignNewPiece }></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export {
    X1Y1
}
```